# Flutter: close app on back press is not working

Tags: android, dart, flutter

In the app, on starting splash screen appears after that I reach to the login screen where there is no app bar or back button but I'm able to back from device back button. I don't want to back on the splash screen when the back is pressed from login screen. I tried many solutions but they are not working.

```
class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'xyz',
      home: LoginPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

    );
  }
}


class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
          if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
            Navigator.pop(context);  // i tried both the way
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          } else {
            SystemNavigator.pop();
          }
        }, 
        child:Scaffold(
      body: Container(.........................//here is my desiging stuff
```

I also tried `return Future.value(false);` with true and false value –

Splash screen code

```
 @override
  void initState (){
    super.initState();
    // TODO initial state stuff
    new Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 2),
            () => Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Use Navigator.pushReplacement instead of Navigator.push

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply pass empty function to - `WillPopScope` widget.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {},   // Empty Function.
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(), //here is my desiging stuff
        ));
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
        appBar: AppBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you never want to goto Splash Screen.

It's Better to use:

```
Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
```

Comment: still I'm reaching to splash screen.

Comment: I also tried `return Future.value(false);` with true and false value

Comment: How are you pushing from Splash to Login .?

Comment: Updated the Answer - best is to Use - `Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));`

Comment: No Issue of onWillPop then .

Comment: it is working when i changed  `push` to `pushReplacement` but the code  of `WillPopScope` remain same,

Comment: when i use `return Future.value(false);` and blank `WillPopScope `  not exiting from the app but `pushReplacement ` is working with my `WillPopScope ` code.

Comment: For Better understanding of Push/Pop - https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code to:

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: ()async => false,
        child:Scaffold(
      body: Container(.........................//here is my desiging stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was because wrongly surrounding `MaterialApp` with `WillPopScope` (instead of surrounding `Scaffold`).

Appreciating @anmol-majhail, here is the correct solution in my case:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      home: WillPopScope(
          child: Scaffold(...),
          onWillPop: () async {
            return false;
          }),
    );
  }
```